# Perl script to gather WMI data on screensaver usage

Tags: perl, scripting

I am very new to scripting/programming and WMI but I have been tasked with gathering information from a list of systems to see if the screensavers are active or not. I need to be able to then store the information to a file and have a cron job run every 10 minutes or so and append the results to said file.

There is noting in there as of yet to write to the file as I am stumped on just getting it to return the correct information in the first place.

Any pointers you guys can provide would be great.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $file = 'hosts.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  { 
    my $user = "uid";
    my $password = "pwd";
    my $server = $line;
    my $result = `wmic -U domain/$user%"$password" //$server "select * from Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'LogonUI.exe'"`;
    my @results = split(/\n/,$result);
    my @tmparray = split(/\|/, @results[2]);
    my $isActive = 0;

    use POSIX qw/strftime/;

    if (@tmparray[0] eq 'LogonUI.exe') {
        $isActive = 1;
    }
    else {
        $isActive = 0;
    }

    print strftime("Date:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S, ", localtime(time));
    print "Host:$server, Screensaver IsActive:$isActive,\n";
}
```

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why do you need to monitor whether screensavers are on or not?

Comment: Also, you might consider using [DBD::WMI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::WMI) instead of calling `wmic` in backticks. I haven't used it but it should give you a cleaner interface; you wouldn't have to worry about nested quotes, among other things.

Comment: I was asked to find a way to see if a user was actually using the system. This was about the best way I could think of. There might be better options in the future as we are in the middle of upgrading the management systems. I will look into the DBD::WMI as that sounds like it might take care of some issues I just ran into. I ended up writing another script to take care of the file read/write but the issue now is what to do if a system returns a value other than LogonUI.exe such as NTSTATUS: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED or just timed out. Now it sees it as being active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`Win32::OLE`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aOLE) supports the creation of management objects. I've used it like so:

```
Win32::OLE->GetObject( "winmgmts:\\\\$host\\$path" );
```

And then with that object called the `ExecQuery` method on it:

```
$wmi->ExecQuery( 
      $query
     , 'WQL'
     , (  ( $flags // 0 ) 
       || wbemFlagReturnImmediately | wbemFlagForwardOnly
       )
     );
```

I've only used this on my local machine to change my IP configuration, automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I will start working on something to see if that will do what we need.